# Denying Direct Access(Download) to all files within a folder in WAMP

Tags: php, apache, video, wamp, httpd.conf

I am creating a video sharing site, in which videos are uploaded by registered users and are played according to their request by checking their permissions.

That is by checking if the user is allowed to view the video or not ?

Bur Problem arises when another user knows the full path to the video file say : localhost/lilUtube/video/myvid.mp4

Then (s)he is directly able to download the video.

What i want is :

- Can i Deny entire directory (video in this case) or files in the directory for direct downloads ? using php script or any other method ?
- But the files are still accessible for other files in that site (that is for all files in folder lilUtube)

Can any one help me in this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably place the videos outside of the web directory if the only supported way to view them will be via a PHP script.  Just give a download link to a PHP script and have the PHP script perform authentication and authorization and then serve up the video with appropriate headers..  The video files do not need to be in a web directory for this.

Comment: It can be done on localhost (On my PC). But what if i shipped site on real server. Will server administrator allow me to do so ?

Comment: @VedantTerkar If you get a real host and not some crap shared host, yes.